# React Native: How to compute x, y and z axis rotation angles based on gyroscope sensor outputs?

Tags: javascript, react-native, rotation, accelerometer, gyroscope

I was able to achieve a 2D rotation on X-Axis using x and y values but would like to compute Y-Axis and Z-Axis rotation angles.

Below is the formula that I have used for computing xAngle rotaion.

`var xAngle = Math.atan2(x, y)/(Math.PI/180)`

where x and y are the gravitational values on x and y-axis provided by the gyroscope sensor respectively.

Can someone help me by sharing a similar set of formulae for yAngle and zAngle computations?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

## Homework

Having just done the maths on this myself, there are some caveats you might want to be aware of.

Lets start by taking a quick look at the axis and using the correct names. Pitch, roll, and yaw describe the rotation around each of the axis. See https://sidvind.com/wiki/Yaw,_pitch,_roll_camera for more information.

Also, everything is relative. The sensors might be relative to one way of thinking, whilst the desired way of thinking might be relative to another.

### My solution

In my case, the relative aspect is the tablet in landscape (landscape-left: rotated 90° counter-clockwise) then laid flat on its back (upright has a pitch of 90°).

The accelerometer readings (that I use) are relative to portrait upright.

Relative to gravity, the rotation around the y-axis can't be calculated from accelerometer information. This means:

- Pitch can't be calculated when portrait and upright
- Roll can't be calculated when flat on a desk
- Yaw can't be calculated when landscape and upright

```
pitch = Math.atan2(-x, -z) * 180 / Math.PI;// In degrees
roll = Math.atan2(-y, -x) * 180 / Math.PI;// In degrees
yaw = Math.atan2(y, -z) * 180 / Math.PI;// In degrees
```

### Assuming the sensors and the desired way of thinking match

- Pitch can't be calculated when landscape and upright
- Roll can't be calculated when flat on a desk
- Yaw can't be calculated when portrait and upright

```
pitch = Math.atan2(z, -y) * 180 / Math.PI;// In degrees
roll = Math.atan2(x, -y) * 180 / Math.PI;// In degrees
yaw = Math.atan2(-x, -z) * 180 / Math.PI;// In degrees
```

### Your solution

Your x-axis rotation matches the pitch on neither of these (nor gets close, negating the symbols), which suggests you're not calculating the rotation around the x-axis, but rotation of the x-axis around another, most likely the z-axis rotation (roll).